# call a php script for every row in my database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but I don't now how to call a php script for every row from my table. I'm using mysql. (I will use PDO in the future, I know it's better). this is my "select" page ( where I select the rows that I want):

```
<?php
include "util.php";
conn();
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM profiles where name='beatrice'"; //it's just an example
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $id= $db_field['id'] ;
                        $nome= strtolower($db_field['name']);
                        $cognome= strtolower($db_field['surname']);
                        $filenome= strtolower($db_field['filename']);
                        $cf= $db_field['cf'];
                        $dir1 = mb_substr($cf, 0, 8);
                        $dir=$id.$dir1;
                        mkdir('test/doc/'.$dir, 0777, TRUE);
                        mkdir('test/doc/'.$dir.'/foto', 0777, TRUE);
                        mkdir('test/doc/'.$dir.'/thumbnails', 0777, TRUE);
                        header('Location:renamer.php?dir='.$dir.'&nome='.$nome.'&filenome='.$filenome.'&id='.$id);
    }

    ?>
```

Header location doesn't work, so I'm searching for another way to do it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Sure you can try and call it but a browser will only open 1 page, unless you opened say 20 new windows using javascript etc. What is it you actually want your web user to see?

Comment: Is there more than one row containing the same username? Because if not, you can get rid of while(). Also, you're missing ' in $cognome.

Comment: I want to rename the files that belong to a certain user, so i have to call a php file that renames the files and puts them in the right directories, for every user in my database table. Now it's doing exactly what you said...opens only 1 window renaming the files that belong to the last user. I don't want to use header location, I don't need a window or more to open, I would like it to be done in the background, but I don't know how.

Comment: yes, there is more than one...the select is only for example, it's not the real one ( it's what I use to test it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **CURL** call.

OR just call a function to do what you want within the loop.

So just create a function (from the functionality within renamer.php) which takes the URL params as the arguments and off you go!

If you *REALLY* need to do it in the background look into - **http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php** - which will launch a new PHP process to execute something, if you go down this route it will get complicated and your task will need to report in some way so you know what has/has not been done :)

Comment: I mentioned CURL, as he could implement the functionality via a REST api.

Comment: I wanted to do a function, but I thought that maybe there is something like header location that I could use...I'll try with a function

Answer (score 0):

How about using mysql_fetch_array() to get results in an array, then array_walk() to execute a function for each row?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: It could work, but I prefer to make a function...seems like it's the quickest way to do it. Thank you.