# How can I call a function on each row of a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql, cursor

I've been trying to solve a problem for a while now and looked at methods such as cursors and while loops. However, I think that perhaps these are not necessary for my purposes. I am using MS SQL Studio 2012. I have a column in my table that has variable string data separated by semicolon like (I was sent this data):

```
THIS IS ONE COLUMN:
245;345;2114;
3421;34;
31;
```

I am trying to separate the data into the number of columns based on semicolons like:

```
FIRST COLUMN    |  SECOND COLUMN   | THIRD COLUMN   | etc
245                345                2114
3421               34
31
```

I have a function that can separate each row by semicolons into a table. Calling the function on one row:
"3421;34" in old table becomes:

```
ID  |  DATA
1      3421
2      34
```

My question is, how can I apply this function to every row in my main table. Should I use a while loop (this might take forever!)? Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101160/call-a-php-script-for-every-row-in-my-database-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a quick and dirty solution, two [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) functions will do the work:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 1), ';', -1) col1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 2), ';', -1) col2,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 3), ';', -1) col3,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 4), ';', -1) col4,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 5), ';', -1) col5
FROM
  yourtable
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/adaac/2). Please notice that this will work because every column teminates with a `;`, and that you will get EMPTY columns and not NULL columns if a value is not present in the column.

**Edit:** if you need to update an existing table, you need to add some new columns first:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN col1 VARCHAR(20);
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN col2 VARCHAR(20);
...
```

you can then launch an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  col1=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 1), ';', -1),
  col2=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 2), ';', -1),
  col3=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 3), ';', -1),
  col4=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 4), ';', -1),
  col5=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ';', 5), ';', -1)
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57489/1). This query is limited to 5 columns, you can add more if you need.

Comment: But how would I apply this to each row in my table?

Comment: @user2522217 do you want to create a new table with the new columns? or do you want to update an existing table?

Comment: I want to update an existing table (adding these new columns). from what I understand your code will work for each row of my table (my table is enormous, each row in the column I'm interested in has multiple semicolons). thanks for the reply btw

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could upvote you but not enough rep =(. ALso I just found out apparently there is a very easy way to do this in Excel (Text to Columns) but the SQL is nice to know.

Comment: @user2522217 you're welcome :) this is not standard SQL but works in MySQL, other DBMS have similar functions.... if you have a text file you can try to import it as a CSV, it might be faster! btw if you wish you can accept this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work tnx!